# Show hidden div on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hidden div element called "contactbox". The DIV contains a message form and some links. I would like "contactbox" to be shown once the link called "contact" is clicked, but my JQuery doesn't want to cooperate:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#contact").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#contactbox").show("slow");
        });

    });
    </script>
```

The "contactbox" element also contains a child element called "Leave" in the top left corner, that will hide it if clicked afterwards, kind of like closing a window that you just opened on your computer. I figured that the JQuery for this would be the following, am I correct?

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#Leave").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#contactbox").hide("slow");
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Put your HTML markup...

Comment: first off, it must be `visibility:hidden`not `none`

Comment: secondly divs on their own don't have a "default" onclick action, so you could remove `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: I should probably change contactbox to display:none instead of visibility:hidden;... But I looked up other questions before asking and I couldn't find a good answer. I don't feel this is a duplicate.